# How to “mock” navigato.geolocation.getCurrentposition in a Vue Jest Test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I'm trying to test my Google Maps component in vue and the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() is within the method

This test fails, printing out this in the console:

The error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined

```
  167 |     },
  168 |     geolocate: function() {
> 169 |       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      | ^
```

This is my code

```
          export default {
            name: "GoogleMap",
            data() {

            },

            created() {

            },

            mounted() {
              this.geolocate();
            },

            methods: {
              ..............
              geolocate: function() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                  this.center = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                  };
                });
              ...............
            },
            computed: {

            }
          };

          </script>
```

I have tried to mock it but I it has no effect

```
    describe("Maps.vue", () => {
      it("renders ... Google maps ", () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Maps, { 

           mocks : {
            getCurrentPosition:()=> jest.fn()

           },
         })
        expect().....
      })
    })
```

How can I "mock" out this navigator method and get the test to pass?